# Node.js - Error Unexpected Identifier

Tags: node.js

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 on vagrant to run this node.js.
node version is v6.2.2.

this is my code. i try to browsing for the solution using the keyword "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" but no luck.

```
function SignalFire(ID, startingLogs) {
    this.fireID = ID;
    this.logsLeft = startingLogs;
}

SignalFire.prototype = {
    addLogs: function(numLogs) {
        this.logsLeft += numLogs;
    }

    lightFire: function() {
        console.log("Whooosh!");
    }
 }
```

this is the error i got:

```
/vagrant/inheritance.js:11
        lightFire: function() {
        ^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:513:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at run (node.js:348:7)
    at startup (node.js:140:9)
    at node.js:463:3
```

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: You are missing a `,` between the 2 methods.

Comment: @Vohuman sure thats the problem, the guy in tutorial doesn't explain about it. thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. As a  suggestion. if you want to be a serious JavaScript developer, before reading any tutorials, learn the basics of JavaScript. MDN has good documentation. Here is a related topic: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals

Comment: yeah, for sure. thank you for the recommendation @Vohuman